# Handling a href in an API Script

Tags: api, google-apps-script, spotify

I am using Google Apps Script to pull from the Spotify API. I am able to extract almost everything, but I get struck when there's an href..

My code below will extract the playlist name but not the artist name after the href... ideas?

MY code -

```
function artistName(playlist_id) {
  //searches spotify and returns artist ID
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/" + playlist_id + "/tracks", 
  { method: "GET",
    headers:{
      "contentType": "application/json",
      'Authorization': "Bearer REMOVED FOR SECURITY"
            },
  });
  json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var listName = [];
  for(var i = 0, len = data.items.length; i < len; i++){
    listName.push(data.items[i].track.album.name); //will return the album name, but I want it to return the artist name after href
                 }
  return listName;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the issue is how you're accessing the object values.

The correct order would be `data.items[i].track.album.artists[0].name`

The complete script with modification would look like this:

```
function artistName(playlist_id) {
  //searches spotify and returns artist ID
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/" + playlist_id + "/tracks", 
  { method: "GET",
    headers:{
      "contentType": "application/json",
      'Authorization': "Bearer REMOVE FOR SECURITY"
    },
  });
  json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var listName = [];
  for(var i = 0, len = data.items.length; i < len; i++){
    listName.push(data.items[i].track.album.artists[0].name);//this will return the artist name after href
  }

  /* For multiple artists
  for(var i = 0, len = data.items.length; i < len; i++){
    var artists = data.items[i].track.album.artists;
    artists.forEach((artist) => {
      listName.push(artist.name);
    });
  }
  */
  return listName;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes you're right. Thank you so much! This is my first year of experience so your help means everything to me!